# A property of pullbacks.

Tags: category-theory

In a regular category, let the following two squares be pullbacks:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A @>a'>> B\\
    @V b' V V @VV b V\\
    C @>>a> D
\end{CD}
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A @>a'>> B\\
    @V c' V V @VV c V\\
    C @>>a> D
\end{CD}
with $a$ a regular epimorphism. Is it true that $b=c$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason for this to be the case. For example, in *any* category the square
\begin{CD}
    A @>{id_A}>> A\\
    @V b V V @VV b V\\
    C @>>{id_C}> C
\end{CD}
is a pullback, no matter what $b$ is; so you can get a counterexample by simply taking any two objects $A,C$ with more than one arrow between them.