# Pullback and kernel pairs

Tags: category-theory

In a regular category,consider two diagrams:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A @>a'>> B\\
    @V b' V V @VV b V\\
    C @>>a> D
\end{CD}
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A @>a'>> B\\
    @V c' V V @VV c V\\
    C @>>a> D
\end{CD}
with $a$ a regular epimorphism, $(A, b',c')$ the kernel pair of a morphism $g\colon C\to E$, $(B, b,c)$ the kernel pair of a morphism $f\colon D\to F$, $v\colon E\to F$ such that $vg=fa$ and $a'\colon A\to B$ the morphism uniquely induced by universality of the kernel pair of $f$. Therefore, the two squares are commutative. Assume now that they are both pullbacks. Is it true that $b=c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the category of $R$-modules, where $R=\mathbb Z$ for concreteness, take

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    R^2 @= R^2\\
    @V \pi_1,\pi_2 V V @VV \pi_1,\pi_2 V\\
    R @= R\\
    @VVV @VVV\\
    0 @= 0
\end{CD}

Fo $f$ and $g$ are the zero map $R\to 0,$ while $b$ is one projection $R^2\to R$ and $c$ is the other projection.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as the square
\begin{CD}
    C @>a>> D\\
    @V g V V @VV f V\\
    E @>>{v}> F
\end{CD}
is a pullback, your two squares formed with the kernel pairs will be pullbacks (and if $g$ is a regular epimorphism the condition is also necessary), but $b=c$ if and only if $f$ is a monomorphism. Since obviously (assuming your category is not trivial) you can find a pullback as above where $f$ is not a monomorphism (see for example [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2598070/245577) to your previous question), it is not true that $b$ must be equal to $c$ in your context.